# SDL support for macos and ios

Tags: opengl, graphics, sdl, metal, vulkan

I have recently came to know that 'Apple' planned to remove openGl support in near future. So I am in the search of an alternative. Does SDL tool support VULKAN / Metal backend for macOs and IOS?

Comment: There [appears to be](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_HINT_RENDER_DRIVER) a Metal backend. There's also the `SDL_Vulkan_` family of functions, allowing you to use Vulkan directly, but it's not listed as a backend. Also there are implementations of OpenGL [on top of Metal](https://moltengl.com/), and probably Vulkan too.